# why does keras give me so many weights in the array, and what are they for?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import random

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(2,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

print(model.summary())

print("\n")

print(model.weights[0])
print(model.weights[1])
print(model.weights[2])
print(model.weights[3])
print(model.weights[4])
print(model.weights[5])
```

The above gives me six arrays of weights. I understand weights[0] is a 2x20 set of connections, but then weights[1] is just 20 members in the array, presumably one for each neuron. But I thought that weights were between each connection, so what is this exactly?

Results:

```
Model: "sequential_11"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_11 (Flatten)         (None, 2)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_33 (Dense)             (None, 20)                60        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_34 (Dense)             (None, 20)                420       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_35 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 21        
=================================================================
Total params: 501
Trainable params: 501
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None


<tf.Variable 'dense_33/kernel:0' shape=(2, 20) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.08592772, -0.4262397 ,  0.32593143,  0.40175033, -0.11370629,
         0.29291457, -0.33887625,  0.09051579, -0.11669007,  0.15766495,
        -0.03898111,  0.47355425,  0.4038219 , -0.16283795, -0.52166206,
         0.08563775,  0.10119641,  0.35014063, -0.29258126,  0.11257637],
       [ 0.32310146, -0.00564504, -0.39950165,  0.3422314 , -0.1736508 ,
        -0.15470237,  0.03384084, -0.50031585,  0.17582124, -0.20669848,
         0.38023835,  0.45190394,  0.22054166, -0.3583283 , -0.31276733,
        -0.42144495,  0.05265975,  0.28793246, -0.12343103, -0.52028173]],
      dtype=float32)>
<tf.Variable 'dense_33/bias:0' shape=(20,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>
<tf.Variable 'dense_34/kernel:0' shape=(20, 20) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.3640272 , -0.1974021 , -0.18908244,  0.36629468, -0.19073088,
         0.3649723 ,  0.20782089,  0.3469664 ,  0.07804716,  0.31226724,
        -0.29463375,  0.1686036 , -0.20033775,  0.30975252,  0.02273259,
        -0.20266692, -0.27747104,  0.20879221, -0.01603091, -0.18493965],
       [ 0.35550284, -0.05491427,  0.17644823, -0.33692163, -0.19445068,
        -0.04921806, -0.32028157, -0.25789088, -0.2392104 ,  0.2923655 ,
        -0.13487688,  0.07437733, -0.08911327, -0.05451488,  0.26065683,
        -0.15244626,  0.16566378,  0.35106057,  0.2891826 , -0.31660333],
       [ 0.27196383,  0.06386155, -0.00255299, -0.08238894,  0.10117772,
        -0.1466422 , -0.3506349 , -0.17026383,  0.37896347,  0.38407606,
         0.11256388,  0.04563713, -0.37850204, -0.02221993,  0.10061872,
         0.3318779 ,  0.02184781, -0.2571288 , -0.3272443 , -0.30387318],
       [-0.30832642, -0.26533905, -0.17655498, -0.17255014, -0.25053996,
        -0.23460795,  0.35648036,  0.25864762,  0.2033844 , -0.1375912 ,
        -0.21034713,  0.23340106,  0.07856712,  0.06940717,  0.3642025 ,
        -0.10192937,  0.3174355 , -0.16317467,  0.12438256,  0.34762514],
       [ 0.29233575, -0.23410663,  0.17361456, -0.35682717,  0.29746616,
        -0.13978545,  0.19865829, -0.32398444,  0.27369195,  0.29182   ,
         0.28845608,  0.3714251 , -0.00226831, -0.11382625, -0.03799275,
        -0.38083866,  0.13849735, -0.17412637,  0.30680603, -0.32791764],
       [-0.36856598, -0.01098448,  0.2209788 , -0.01641467,  0.36460286,
         0.3742503 , -0.07144001, -0.32689905, -0.2800351 , -0.26420033,
        -0.3203124 ,  0.22266299,  0.05407029,  0.20716977,  0.23186374,
         0.34451336, -0.3665755 , -0.08111835,  0.02044231,  0.22657269],
       [-0.18087737, -0.09122089, -0.3162348 , -0.01350608,  0.2994557 ,
         0.00759923,  0.07653233, -0.11245179, -0.06106046,  0.09489083,
        -0.34051555, -0.0210776 , -0.3720226 , -0.08034962, -0.3628871 ,
        -0.08755568,  0.13865143, -0.13755408,  0.18153298,  0.23439962],
       [-0.36453527, -0.3077588 ,  0.06971669,  0.23991793, -0.32902858,
        -0.1256682 , -0.37355578, -0.22176625, -0.06080669,  0.12455881,
         0.02237046,  0.21177506,  0.05803809, -0.07626435, -0.36375207,
         0.13273174,  0.15075874, -0.18664922,  0.20256019,  0.17832053],
       [-0.09238327,  0.03065437,  0.04975492,  0.03068706, -0.01132107,
         0.04134732,  0.2726786 ,  0.09169459,  0.16609359, -0.26199952,
         0.34235936, -0.3293307 , -0.2625829 ,  0.05643666, -0.19363837,
        -0.09321746,  0.15029383,  0.1271655 , -0.13643244, -0.1260187 ],
       [-0.10736805,  0.08597881, -0.28592098,  0.32719833,  0.25863254,
        -0.35738683,  0.28420174,  0.07898697,  0.12083912,  0.24187142,
         0.20364356,  0.16368687,  0.3372751 , -0.11902198,  0.29610634,
        -0.26228833,  0.26691556,  0.02676412,  0.20875496,  0.2742722 ],
       [-0.01111042,  0.01864234, -0.3684872 ,  0.25593793,  0.05572906,
        -0.27395982, -0.18536313, -0.28665859,  0.33866453, -0.04277194,
         0.31874043,  0.17231691,  0.26513118,  0.2841534 ,  0.38413507,
         0.32093495, -0.1821885 ,  0.3448484 ,  0.06886706,  0.05471361],
       [ 0.27029324,  0.17785454, -0.3417698 , -0.18585834,  0.13658857,
         0.25487036, -0.34464136, -0.31934893, -0.07558686,  0.12984264,
        -0.12386304,  0.33101034,  0.2395941 , -0.35495222, -0.38362566,
         0.02023152, -0.38369113,  0.10231277, -0.00923318, -0.2564116 ],
       [ 0.3738134 , -0.13709581, -0.02727005, -0.38571945, -0.17950383,
        -0.08438393, -0.35748094, -0.02563897, -0.26492482, -0.3148442 ,
         0.27745587,  0.01215285,  0.0338603 ,  0.22927964, -0.26310933,
         0.17490405,  0.15125847,  0.33357888, -0.10504535,  0.09216848],
       [-0.18665901,  0.14127249, -0.31025392,  0.3109604 ,  0.11353964,
         0.1544854 , -0.0628956 ,  0.2526992 , -0.38535342, -0.35054773,
         0.3639174 , -0.22744954,  0.2787813 ,  0.25469422, -0.24284746,
         0.2586198 ,  0.38151866,  0.14534372, -0.07336038,  0.35205972],
       [-0.0222263 , -0.09051144,  0.19810867,  0.2596696 ,  0.16493648,
        -0.15432249, -0.12816939,  0.26651537,  0.33925128,  0.24480599,
        -0.20886998, -0.23604779,  0.35640693, -0.1257923 , -0.3385602 ,
         0.37019014, -0.34767368, -0.20191407,  0.05838048, -0.3322008 ],
       [-0.22849075,  0.31127506, -0.1032331 ,  0.03278631, -0.3802262 ,
         0.06519806, -0.10763076, -0.23816115,  0.29874003, -0.17749721,
        -0.10582674, -0.03064901,  0.18550068,  0.08624834,  0.09579298,
        -0.305739  ,  0.00272122,  0.14033073,  0.22830683, -0.17147864],
       [-0.23749031, -0.36036015, -0.15639098,  0.16943222,  0.33908015,
        -0.18797807, -0.31251115,  0.13584453, -0.10717931, -0.11736256,
         0.17281443,  0.1897279 , -0.35898107,  0.21381551,  0.3051238 ,
         0.12489098,  0.29044586, -0.20301346, -0.25790715,  0.04153055],
       [-0.25941753, -0.3507824 ,  0.34750968, -0.04910356, -0.1914334 ,
        -0.22343925,  0.3420688 ,  0.38251758, -0.09309632,  0.3546936 ,
        -0.22427556, -0.24499758,  0.00074324, -0.06633586,  0.1922136 ,
         0.11927372, -0.19837731, -0.23528719, -0.26004478, -0.24688683],
       [-0.03148285, -0.32766464, -0.2530514 ,  0.1765365 ,  0.26583946,
        -0.18146862, -0.20307828, -0.07899943, -0.10167924, -0.05031338,
         0.03324467, -0.27283487, -0.3672278 , -0.24607424, -0.15097658,
         0.18689764, -0.32162574,  0.10529301, -0.2671068 , -0.29016626],
       [ 0.23749584, -0.10357189,  0.03281826,  0.30171496,  0.3568563 ,
        -0.27596533,  0.3714081 ,  0.04653817,  0.14261234, -0.18491131,
         0.3152057 ,  0.23654068,  0.07070702,  0.0457052 , -0.17505457,
         0.15374076, -0.03659964,  0.2212556 , -0.05467528,  0.160887  ]],
      dtype=float32)>
<tf.Variable 'dense_34/bias:0' shape=(20,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>
<tf.Variable 'dense_35/kernel:0' shape=(20, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.44639164],
       [ 0.46424013],
       [-0.36026257],
       [-0.19160783],
       [-0.236644  ],
       [ 0.36841106],
       [ 0.5083434 ],
       [-0.00797582],
       [ 0.25151885],
       [-0.51940155],
       [-0.03726539],
       [-0.15949944],
       [-0.2284751 ],
       [ 0.4611426 ],
       [ 0.2685169 ],
       [ 0.1900658 ],
       [-0.4574982 ],
       [ 0.22935611],
       [-0.46032292],
       [-0.28261   ]], dtype=float32)>
<tf.Variable 'dense_35/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: Can you also show the result?. Will be helpful, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.weights` return all the weights. Your understanding is correct. `weights[0]` is a 2x20 set of connections & `weights[1]` is the weights for the corresponding bias. Since, you are using `tf.keras.layers.Dense` which has `use_bias=True` by default. So, `weight[1]` is referring to bias weights for the first Dense layer. Same is true for all the other Dense layers. Try setting any of them to `use_bias=False` & you will notice the difference. For example -

```
model = keras.Sequential([ 
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(2,)), 
keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu, use_bias=False), 
keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu), 
keras.layers.Dense(1) 
])
```

```
len(model.weights)
```

This gives u a list of 5. It ignores the bias weights for the first layer.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize that biases were "weights" I thought of them as very separate ideas. Thank you!